# how to get public key from self signed SSL certificate at client side . (using js)

Tags: encryption, ssl-certificate, public-key-encryption

i want to send the encrypted password from client to server using public key by my self sign SSL certificate.
so problem is how to access the public key from ssl certificate so that i can encrypt the password send it to server .

Comment: If you use nodejs builtin `crypto`, which would not be the case if by client you mean browser, you can read an X.509 certificate in PEM format into a KeyObject for the publickey; see [createPublicKey](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createpublickey_key) and [publicEncrypt](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_publicencrypt_key_buffer) which calls it if needed.

If you use `node-forge` (which is browserable, despite the name) read the cert with `pki.certificateFromPem` or `...Asn1` then use the `.publickey` field.